# Why is $\phi$ an epimorphism of rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

$$\phi:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_m$$
$$\phi(a)=[a]_m$$

Why is $\phi$ an epimorphism of rings ? A surjective function is when $$\forall y, \exists x : f(x)=y$$ Isn't it??
Is $\phi$ surjective because both $x$ and $y$ are related with $a$??

Comment: Another word for a "surjective" function is "onto" if that helps you. Also don't forget for $\phi$ to be an epimorphism, you need to show it preserves the structure of the ring in addition to being surjective.

Comment: If each element of some set is of the form "something of $a$" where $a$ is from some other set, then the map "take something of ..." is clearly a surjective map from that other set to the given set. - if $A=\{\,f(x)\mid x\in B\,\}$ then $f\colon B\to A$, $x\mapsto f(x)$ is clearly onto.

Comment: Ok!!! Thank you both!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because for any $[a] \in \mathbb{Z}_m$, the same $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is mapped to it.

In fact all numbers $b$ of the form $b=mq+a$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z}$ are mapped to $[a]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_m$.

Moreover, this shows that $\phi$ is not injective. Since $b=mq$ is mapped to $[0] \in \mathbb{Z}_m$ then the kernel is $\ker{\phi}=m \mathbb{Z}$.

---

More generally, if $R$ is an equivalence relation on the set $X$, i.e. $R \times R \subseteq X$ is a reflexive, symmetric and transitive relation then the map that sends each element in $X$ to its equivalence class in $X/R$ is a surjective map.

Please review elementary set theory if you have not mastered this stuff yet. You'll need to know these things well to study abstract algebra.

Comment: @MaryStar: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Think $Z_m=\{0,1,2,...,m-1\}$ if $a\in Z_m$ then $a\in Z$ and $a\cong a \mod (m)$

Comment: you are welcome :)